# How can I loop inside a loop and sort results from a JSON object via AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I'm currently working on creating a dynamic carousel that is built by using data from a JSON object with the following basic structure:

```
[{
    "category": {
        "href": "somecategory/categoryid",
        "id": "somecategory/categoryid",
        "ID": "CATEGORYID01",
        "name": "Orders",
        "locale": "gb",
        "position": 2,
        "outdated": false,
        "slug": "category-1",
        "icon": ""
    },
    "articles": [{
            "href": "somearticle/articleid",
            "id": "somearticle/articleid",
            "ID": "ARTICLEID01",
            "position": 1,
            "voteUpCount": 94,
            "voteDownCount": 1105,
            "categories": [{
                "position": 1,
                "category": "CATEGORYID01"
            }],
            "keywords": [
                "Missing-order"
            ],
            "title": "Article 1 title",
            "body": "<p>article body</p>",
            "locale": "gb",
            "outdated": false,
            "slug": "article-1",
            "views": 0,
            "labelName": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        {
            "href": "somearticle/articleid",
            "id": "somearticle/articleid",
            "ID": "ARTICLEID02",
            "position": 2,
            "voteUpCount": 94,
            "voteDownCount": 1105,
            "categories": [{
                "position": 1,
                "category": "CATEGORYID01"
            }],
            "keywords": [
                "Missing-order"
            ],
            "title": "Article 2 title",
            "body": "<p>article body</p>",
            "locale": "gb",
            "outdated": false,
            "slug": "article-2",
            "views": 0,
            "labelName": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        {
            "href": "somearticle/articleid",
            "id": "somearticle/articleid",
            "ID": "ARTICLEID03",
            "position": 3,
            "voteUpCount": 94,
            "voteDownCount": 1105,
            "categories": [{
                "position": 1,
                "category": "CATEGORYID01"
            }],
            "keywords": [
                "Missing-order"
            ],
            "title": "Article 3 title",
            "body": "<p>article body</p>",
            "locale": "gb",
            "outdated": false,
            "slug": "article-3",
            "views": 0,
            "labelName": [
                ""
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

The above structure repeats depending on how many categories there are, so you have CATEGORIES with the ARTICLES that belong to that category right below it (also identified by the category ID inside the articles data), so for example, if you have 2 categories the JSON structure would be:

```
[{
   "category":{},
   "articles":[{several articles here}],

   "category":{},
   "articles":[{several articles here}]
}]
```

I have already managed to create the dynamic slides for the carousel, creating one slide per each category available within the JSON, but now I have to populate each category slide with all the articles belonging to that particular category. The code I'm using to create the slides is the following:

```
function getfaqsCarousel(){
    faqsCarousel().then((data) => { // THE AJAX CALL IS ON ITS OWN SEPARATE FUNCTION ( faqsCarousel() )
        var article_data = '';
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            var category = value.category.slug;
            var catname = value.category.name;
            var position = value.category.position;
            var catid = value.category.ID;
            var articleid = value.articles.categories.category;
            
            if (category != 'faqs-home') {
                article_data += `<div>
                    <div class="cc-box">
                        <div class="cc-hoverbox"> <span> <img alt="faqIcon" src="`+ value.category.icon +`" /> </span>
                            <h3>`+ catname +`</h3>
                            <ul class="feature-list">
                               <li>articles here</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <a class="viewBtn" href="javascript:void(0)" data-category="`+ catid +`" data-slug="`+ category +`">See All</a> </div>
                </div>`; 
            }
        });
        
        $('.faq-slider').html(article_data);
        
        $('.faq-slider').slick({
            lazyLoad: "progressive",
            slidesToShow: 3,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    arrows: true,
                    centerMode: !0,
                    centerPadding: "40px",
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }]
        })
    });
}
    
getfaqsCarousel();
```

Now, inside that `$.each` loop, I need to loop through all the articles for each category to replace the part of the code `<li>articles here</li>`

So my question is: **How can I loop through all the articles inside the already existing categories loop and at the same time, SORT the results by the `position` property available inside each article?**

Thanks for your time beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getfaqsCarousel() {
    faqsCarousel().then((data) => { // THE AJAX CALL IS ON ITS OWN SEPARATE FUNCTION ( faqsCarousel() )
        var article_data = '';
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            //...more code on top
            var articles = value.articles
            var desiredArticleStructure = ""

            //here sort and loop through all the articles 
            var sortedArticles = articles.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.position - b.position
            })


            sortedArticles.map(article => {
                $('.title').innerText = article.title
                $('.title body').innerHtml = article.body
                //...your structure goes on

                desiredArticleStructure += `
                    <div class='title'>
                        <div class="body"></div>
                    </div>
                `
            })


            if (category != 'faqs-home') {
                article_data += `<div>
                    <div class="cc-box">
                        <div class="cc-hoverbox"> <span> <img alt="faqIcon" src="`+ value.category.icon + `" /> </span>
                            <h3>`+ catname + `</h3>
                            <ul class="feature-list">
                               <li>articles here</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <a class="viewBtn" href="javascript:void(0)" data-category="`+ catid + `" data-slug="` + category + `">See All</a> </div>
                </div>`;
            }

            $('.feature-list').innerHtml = desiredArticleStructure
        });
    });
}

getfaqsCarousel();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I think I get the idea your trying to explain, but I'm a bit confused about how to integrate your solution with my existing work. How can the sorted articles be integrated within my slides string? is the HTML code under `desiredHtml` just the HTML for the articles or this that include the loop for the slides as well? Thanks

Comment: @user3354949 you can check try my updated answer

Comment: I've been tweaking your latest answer to further make it work with my current code, and I have to say this is very close to fully working. The issue I'm having is that the `desiredArticleStructure` is not being included inside each slide. I have been trying to place the function `$('.feature-list').innerHtml = desiredArticleStructure` around several locations and I have tried changing the function to `$('.feature-list').html('<li data-article-id="someid">'+ articleTitle +'</li>')` I have managed to alert the articles correctly but they won't be added to the final render

Comment: I have included my latest code here as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/lep1981/53qyuspa/